# how to change default theme of Devexpress WinForm application

Tags: winforms, devexpress

how to change default theme of Devexpress WinForm application while application is running an well as in Designer mode?

Answer (score 4):

this can be done using the [DefaultLookAndFeel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressLookAndFeelUserLookAndFeel_Defaulttopic) component.  The [How to: Customize the Look And Feel of All the Controls within an Application](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2412) topic explains how to do this in code.

Answer (score 2):

**Source:** [Allowing user selected Global Theme for winform app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165712/allowing-user-selected-global-theme-for-winform-app)

You can use skins to change theme of the entire application. Use the below approach:

In the constructor of your main form calls:

```
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
```

This will enable your form to use the current skin. It is also important that each of your forms derived from XtraForm.

After that you need to setup the global look and feel object for your application:

```
//This set the style to use skin technology
DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.Style = DevExpress.LookAndFeel.LookAndFeelStyle.Skin;

//Here we specify the skin to use by its name           
DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle("Black");
```

References:
[How do I change a DevExpress project's theme after creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593633/how-do-i-change-a-devexpress-projects-theme-after-creation)
[How to: Customize the Look And Feel of All the Controls within an Application](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2412)